# Don't duplicate character - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to have the program print out an error if the character inputted has already been used. If you check the else If statement, it technically runs but I don't want it to print each time. Only when the character has been chosen in another round.

```
while (!userCorrect) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Guessing (round " + roundNumber + "): Choosing your letter from a-z: ");
    String letters = input.nextLine();
    createString(letters.length());
    if (letters.length () > 1) { //code will print an error if the user selects more than 1 character
        System.out.println("You should not enter more than 1 character");
    }
    else if (letters.length()==letters.length()) { //print error if the character has been chosen already
        System.out.println(letters + " has been chosen before, try again");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("end (round " + roundNumber + ")");
        roundNumber++; 
    }
}
```

The closest I got was `letters.length() == letters.length();` but I know that doing this will always print the error. Do you think there's a parameter I can put in there that'll make it skip the first round and only start looking when the second round starts?

Comment: letters.length() is always going to be equal to letters.length(). If you want to check if something has been entered before, you need to store everything that has been entered in a collection (a Set), and check if the collection already contains what has just been entered.

Comment: That isn't all code, what is createString() doing?

Comment: `letters.length() == letters.length()` will always be true. Therefore next line will always print the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you already have an answer but I wanted to point out a few things

- Don't create a new Scanner object each time in the loop
- Use `continue` to avoid nested if-else
- There are a number of ways to store the characters, like using a List or a Set collection or a StringBuffer or a simply a String.
- name your boolean variables is...
- I ignored the createString method and skipped the userCorrect since they are unclear how to use

(I also ended my own exit condition to the loop since just to have one)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int roundNumber = 1;
boolean isUserCorrect = false;

String selected = "";

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Guessing (round " + roundNumber + "): Choosing your letter from a-z: ");
    String letters = input.nextLine();

    if (letters.length () > 1) { //code will print an error if the user selects more than 1 character
        System.out.println("You should not enter more than 1 character");
        continue;
    }

    if (selected.contains(letters)) {
        System.out.println(letters + " has been chosen before, try again");
        continue;
    }

    selected = selected.concat(letters);
    System.out.println("end (round " + roundNumber + ")");
    roundNumber++;
    if (roundNumber > 5) {
        System.out.println("Selected characters: " + selected);
        break;
    }
}
input.close();
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot! I'm pretty new to programming so this helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list where you store the chars, then look if you used the current one before or not.

I think this will help you :

```
List<Character> choosedCharacters = new ArrayList<>();
while (!userCorrect) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Guessing (round " + roundNumber + "): Choosing your letter from a-z: ");
    String letters = input.nextLine();
    createString(letters.length());
    if (letters.length () > 1) { //code will print an error if the user selects more than 1 character
        System.out.println("You should not enter more than 1 character");
    }
    else if (choosedCharacters.contains(letters.charAt(0))) { //print error if the character has been chosen already
        System.out.println(letters + " has been chosen before, try again");
        choosedCharacters.add(letters.charAt(0));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("end (round " + roundNumber + ")");
        choosedCharacters.add(letters.charAt(0));
        roundNumber++;
    }
}
```